# Stop field enlargement by too much text

Tags: html, css

I try to stop, that a text change the size of a field. But changing the width does not change anything.

```css
p {
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p>veryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryverylongtext</p>
```

Thank you for every answer!!

Comment: add `word-break: break-word`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing the width doesn't change any dimensions of the text but it's width. for changing the size of the text you can use  font-size tag just like this. Try also functions just like   font-weight to make the text bold. Try this code and tell me if I helped you. THANKS

```
p {
font-size: 50px;
}

<p>veryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryverylongtext</p>
```

Comment: Hey, is it helpful